# Android ListView duplicating onclicking an item

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am having a problem in my listview. Actually I have implemented Facebook Like Feed from [Facebook Like Custom Feed](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)
which is fetching data from MySQL database. At bottom of every list item I am having a Like Button from this library [Material Favourite Button](https://github.com/IvBaranov/MaterialFavoriteButton). My Problem is that when i click like on 1st List item, The 5th list item gets automatically liked and if i click on 2nd List item 4th list item gets liked and so on. I tried everything i could do but nothing resolved this problem. I tried to add view holder also to my list adapter class as suggested in various answered questions here but it didn't resolve my issue. Kindly Help! Below is my adapter class:

```
 public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;

    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    ViewHolder holder;
      int id = 0;
    String email;

    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice =
                    (MaterialFavoriteButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_anim);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{

            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            //get User Email
            db = new DatabaseHandler(activity.getApplication());
            db = new DatabaseHandler(activity.getApplication());
            HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
            email = user.get("email").toString();
            // End get User Email ID for sending it to db

        //Getting Views from Layout


        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        final TextView like = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_box_no);
        TextView share = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.share_no);
        TextView comment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment_no);
        NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);

        FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);
        //End Getting Views from Layout

        final FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);
        name.setText(item.getName());

        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Check for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // Chcek for empty Like
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getLike())) {
            like.setText(item.getLike());
            like.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            like.setText("0");
        }
        // Chcek for empty Comment
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getComment())) {
            comment.setText(item.getComment());
            comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            comment.setText("0");
        }
        // Chcek for empty Share
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getShare())) {
            share.setText(item.getShare());
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            share.setText("0");
        }
        if (item.getFav().equals("1")) {
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(true, false);
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(false, false);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);
        imageLoader.get(item.getProfilePic(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePic, R.drawable._businessman, R.drawable._businessman));

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Animating the List View
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity.getApplication(), (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
        //End Animating the List View

        //onClick Like


holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setOnFavoriteChangeListener(new MaterialFavoriteButton.OnFavoriteChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFavoriteChanged(MaterialFavoriteButton buttonView, boolean favorite) {
        id = item.getId();
        Log.d("inFavChngeListner", "Clickd" + item.getId());
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication(), "Fav Changed : " + item.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (favorite) {


            new send_json().execute();

        } else {

            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(false, true);
            new send_json_unlike().execute();
        }
    }
});
        return convertView;


    }
     static class ViewHolder {
        MaterialFavoriteButton materialFavoriteButtonNice;
    }

    //Sending Likes with email id and feed id to Remote Mysql Db
    public class send_json extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.isFavorite())
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

            JSONObject json = userFunction.like_func(email, String.valueOf(id));
            Log.d("BG Like, Email:" + email + "Id: " + String.valueOf(id), json.toString());
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
if(!holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.isFavorite())
            holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(true, true);
        }
    }
    //Sending Likes with email id and feed id to Remote Mysql Db
    public class send_json_unlike extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(!holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.isFavorite())
                holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(false, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

            JSONObject json = userFunction.unlike_func(email, String.valueOf(id));
            Log.d("BG UnLike, Email:" + email + "Id: " + String.valueOf(id), json.toString());
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
            if(!holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.isFavorite())
                holder.materialFavoriteButtonNice.setFavorite(false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use ViewHolder instance global . Make it inside function scope . And try to change the logic . Only update the model inside the array and just call notifyDataSetChanged() method. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: Putting ViewHolder inside function scope helped!!! Thanks Alot. Now i am facing another issue that when i scroll the previously liked post gets reset. How can i save the previously liked post so that the user knows which post he liked??

Comment: Did you update your model after the status changes ?